# Maven Profile for testing

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-3

I am developing a java web application (No Spring).I wanted to use separate db for production and testing.I have two files in src/main/resources - env.properties and env.test.properties.
I have defined the profile in pom.xml as mentioned in https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html.

```
 <profiles>
   <profile>
     <id>test</id>
     <build>
       <plugins>
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <phase>test</phase>
               <goals>
                 <goal>run</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                 <tasks>
                   <delete file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/environment.properties"/>
                   <copy file="src/main/resources/environment.test.properties"
                         tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/environment.properties"/>
                 </tasks>
               </configuration>
             </execution>
           </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
             <skip>true</skip>
           </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
             <execution>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                 <goal>jar</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                 <classifier>test</classifier>
               </configuration>
             </execution>
           </executions>
         </plugin>
       </plugins>
     </build>
   </profile>
```

However, when I run test by maven test -Ptest, I see that my test is getting executed with the db from env.properties and then after completion of test , the profile switching happens.
I am also having a jebkins pipeline which builds tests and deploys.
Am I missing something here ? What is the correct way to read the properties from env.test.properties(activate the profile and run test) ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: One hint I can give. If start thinking of using maven-ant-run in a Maven build you are usually doing something wrong. At the point please ask here on SO or ask on the Maven users list... https://maven.apache.org/mail-lists.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're doing this the hard way.

Get rid of the profiles and move the file from `src/main/resources/environment.test.properties` to `src/test/resources/environment.properties`

Resources in `src/test/resources/` will be found and loaded before those in `src/main/resources` when unit tests are being executed.